# Odoo v8 - setup products categories

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I had hours installing odoo v8. I've installed Sales modulo, Warehouse Module, and Ecommerce module.

Product Multi Variants are hidden from the menu, they just appear in the product template

- Product category are not shown anywhere. Anyone can help me with producst categories?

Answer (score 0):

First of all Install "warehouse module" , allow the user to the technical rights from the setting. 
After this click on warehouse and click on product in configuration , In configuration Open Product Category.

Set the Account properties and Account stock Properties.

The remaining I will understand you If you saw this.